# How can I convert SVG coordinates (x,y) defined relatively to an element into absolute coordinates/position?

Tags: svg, d3.js, coordinates, transformation

I am trying to draw a line, connecting two circles in SVG. The circles are - together with underlying rectangles encapsulated in a SVG group elements (). Those groups are positioned with the *transform="translate(x,y)"* attributes.
My problem is, that the coordinates of the elements inside the group are positioned relatively to the origins (0,0 coordinates) of their groups. To place a overlying line I need to know the absolute coordinates.

Here is the code using the D3 javascript library :

```
var body = d3.select("body");

var svg = body.append("svg");

var group1 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(50,50)");

var rect1 = group1.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", 'lightblue');

var circ1 = group1.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", 'red')

var group2 = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(350,50)");

var rect2 = group2.append("svg:rect")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0)
    .attr("width", 100)
    .attr("height", 100)
    .style("fill", 'lightgreen');

var circ2 = group2.append("svg:circle")
    .attr("cx", 50)
    .attr("cy", 50)
    .attr("r", 10)
    .style("fill", 'red');

var line = svg.append("svg:line")
    .attr("x1", parseInt(circ1.attr("cx")))
    .attr("y1", parseInt(circ1.attr("cy")))
    .attr("x2", parseInt(circ2.attr("cx")))
    .attr("y2", parseInt(circ2.attr("cy")))
    .attr("stroke", "black");
```

I do know why the line does not appear. I also know that every SVG element is related to a transformation-matrix. I am not sure how to access the matrices of the circle-elements and how to get the absolute coordinates of them (the cx/cy attributes). Another possibility would be to get the absolute distance of the circles.

Here is a [jsfiddle with the above code](http://jsfiddle.net/WFwTg/)

Comment: It will be much easier if you keep the elements in the same group.

Comment: Yes it will be. But then I have co take care about the position of the circles and rectangles manually. This is the reason why I decided to try the approach with multiple groups.

Answer (score 6):

I think I was able to solve the problem myself. The access to the transformation matrix could be achieved using

```
circ1[0][0].getCTM()
```

or by using

```
circ1[0][0].getScreenCTM()
```

By adding the value of the ***e*** attribute to the ***x*** coordinate and the value of the ***f*** attribute to the ***y*** coordinate I was able to get the "absolute position" of the elements.

Updated jsfiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/WFwTg/1/)

I am afraid my solution is not universally valid. For example I am not sure what happens in a case I will use *transform: scale* before the computation of the position ?

Comment: You got me going in the right direction.  I think reading and understanding chapter 7 of the SVG document will give me the whole story.  I'm assuming the preferred method would be to use the transform matrix and various things like matrix multiply to achieve what you (and I) are trying to do.

Comment: I think you can use the full formula for mapping to a new coordinate system from here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/transform ; absX = a*x + c*y + e and absY = b*x + d*y + f (which in the case of translate transform will simplify to the solution in your current answer)

Comment: By the way, only getScreenCTM seems to return valid data for me. The matrix from getCTM doesn't change the position after applying it.